# What will be the fastest way to level in Mists of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I quickly level up in World of Warcraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/how-can-i-quickly-level-up-in-world-of-warcraft)

Assuming you start out at level 85 and have at least 2 to 3 friends to play with, what will be the fastest way to level to 90 in the Mists of Pandaria expansion?

Is it a combination of questing and running dungeons? Does having a group of friends who play well make running dungeons with them the best choice? Or is it just killing mobs mindlessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of dungeon quests, random dungeon rewards and considering the group xp bonus for killing mobs, running dungeons back-to-back might be competitive with solo questing.

You'll want to make sure you have MoP green gear or better first (ilevel ~320 cata items probably won't be enough to take on MoP dungeons).  Better gear = faster xp in the dungeon, unlike solo questing.

---

The group xp bonus is:

```
3 people: 16.6%
4 people: 30%
5 people: 40%
```

This applies to mob kills and does not apply to quest rewards.

---

MoP [ilevel](http://www.wowpedia.org/Item_level) starts at 372, which is just below 4.3 Justice point rewards.

Comment: What are the rules for Group XP Bonus? Also, what is the starting MoP greens' ilevel?

Answer (score 2):

If Mists is similar to Cataclysm, the absolute fastest way to level would be doing quests as fast as you possibly can and switching zones whenever the quest levels no longer match your level.

Blizzard has always been adamant about making questing the most efficient way to level, as to encourage players to experience the story. Though, if you are speeding through, you'll likely miss a good chunk of it.