# Are there any fast ways to get my sons WoW account to a higher level if he doesn't qualify to SoR?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I quickly level up in World of Warcraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/how-can-i-quickly-level-up-in-world-of-warcraft)

My 11 year old sons highest character is 61. He really wants to play higher end stuff but doesn't have the time to grind up. Scroll of Resurrection can get an inactive player up to 80 which would be great, but he doesn't qualify. Are there any other promotions anyone knows about that can get him there faster?

Thanks.

Comment: If he wants to start a new character, Monks get a repeatable (daily and at certain milestones) quest to get an hour-long buff for a 50% exp bonus. I chain-tanked dungeons with this buff (with full heirlooms & guild perks) and got 24 levels in a couple hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your son does not mind "Starting Over", I would recommend doing RAF (Recruit A Friend), this would allow for your son to level a character super fast to 80 along with being able to do it with yourself or someone else.

For more information on [Recruit a Friend](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/recruit-a-friend-faq)

Comment: Just so Jim can see the basics of how quick it would be: If you send a recruit to him (which I assume you would) you will have to level a toon with him so he can benefit from the Triple Experience. If you are not partied and near the other person, neither person will not get bonus experience. Recruit a Friend lasts for 3 months from the time they accept the invitation. Downsides: If he already has the expansions, he will have to buy them all over again since any games bought to his other account are bound to them.